# Trying to make a custom Arch-based Linux distro with larch

Tags: linux, arch-linux, iso-image, linux-distributions

I'm all set up with a spiffy Arch installation in a virtual machine, and now I want to turn it into a live ISO. When I heard about [larch](http://larch.berlios.de/), I thought it would be the perfect tool to turn my existing installation into something I could distribute.

However, I can't get larch to install properly. I followed the [installation instructions](http://larch.berlios.de/dl/larch_download.html/) on the website, which said to download and run the larch-setup script. When I run it, though, it installs the larch profiles and libraries but doesn't install the executable programs.

Here's a screenshot of the errors I get when larch-setup tries to install the executables.

[image: Screenshot of what happens when I run larch-setup]

I'd greatly appreciate any clues to what is going wrong here, or suggestions for alternative ways to turn my customized Arch installation into an ISO! Thanks!

Comment: Looks like it is looking to the wrong place for something it needs (specifically `tmp/usr/bin`), which doesn't exist by default in anything... You may need to download the script and edit it to view the right thing before it executes. I will take a quick glance at it too..

Answer (score 1):

The issue is occurring in this section of the script:

```
for s in $( ls tmp/usr/bin ); do
    p=$( readlink tmp/usr/bin/${s} )
    d=$( dirname ${p} )
    ln -s larch0/$( basename ${d} )/$( basename ${p}) ${s}
done
rm -rf tmp
```

I try running those individually and get errors, so it seems to me that the symlink is the wrong approach since "tmp" is getting nixed below.

Also, readlink is not echo-ing back anything when I try that. Probably because it is not printing back values, then killing `dirname` and everything below.  Maybe replace that with (though, this is dirty since I don't fully know where the next stuff looks):

```
mkdir -p larch0/tmp/usr/bin
mkdir -p larch0/usr/bin
cp tmp/usr/bin/* larch0/tmp/usr/bin/
cp tmp/usr/bin/* larch0/usr/bin
```

That just copies the same files to those two locations since I don't know what the next script really wants.  I bet it is just `larch0/usr/bin` logically, but whatever.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I've actually given up on larch since contacting the developer, who said he doesn't maintain it anymore and that it probably won't work with new Arch installations.

I'm now trying to build my distro with archiso, but I'm still having problems. I'll save those for another post.

Comment: No worries, glad I didn't rewrite the whole thing like I was considering since I pondered doing this as well.